# How to get oldest part installation of consecutive installations the same boat in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with part installations in boats.
I would like to keep the oldest installation (see `date`) of consecutive installations for each `boat`/`part`. How can I do this?

**Input:**

```
| date  | boat | part
|-------|------|-----
| 01/01 | A    | C <-- Keep this row because this is first install of C in A
| 01/02 | A    | C  
| 01/03 | A    | C
| 01/04 | A    | D <-- Keep this row because this is first install of D in A
| 01/05 | A    | D
| 01/06 | A    | C <-- Keep this row because this is first install of C in A after D
| 01/07 | A    | C
| 01/08 | A    | C
| 01/09 | B    | C <-- Keep this row because this is first install of C in B
| 01/10 | B    | C
```

**Output:**

```
| date  | boat | part
|-------|------|-----
| 01/01 | A    | C
| 01/04 | A    | D
| 01/06 | A    | C
| 01/09 | B    | C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df[df[['boat','part']].ne(df[['boat','part']].shift()).any(axis=1)]
print (df)

    date boat part
0  01/01    A    C
3  01/04    A    D
5  01/06    A    C
8  01/09    B    C
```

**Detail**:

First compare consecutive values with [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and `shift`:

```
print (df[['boat','part']].ne(df[['boat','part']].shift()))
    boat   part
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False   True
4  False  False
5  False   True
6  False  False
7  False  False
8   True  False
9  False  False
```

And then test at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
print (df[['boat','part']].ne(df[['boat','part']].shift()).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
9    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: How can I add a condition that a certain column needs to be `True`? Basically, how to get oldest part installation of consecutive installations in the same boat for rows where column `X` is `True`?

Comment: @dunkubok - Do you think change `df[['boat','part']].ne(df[['boat','part']].shift()).any(axis=1)` to `df[['boat','part']].ne(df[['boat','part']].shift()).any(axis=1) | (df['col'] == 1)` for chained by `OR` or `df[['boat','part']].ne(df[['boat','part']].shift()).any(axis=1)` to `df[['boat','part']].ne(df[['boat','part']].shift()).any(axis=1) & (df['col'] == 1)` for chained by `AND`

Comment: I've tried this with `& (df['col'] == 0)`, but this returns an empty df. I think the problem is that this still executes the `.ne` on all records.

Comment: It should only do the `.ne` on cases that have `col == False`

Comment: @dunkubok - Can you be more specific? Maybe the best create new question with expcted output.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266534/how-to-get-the-oldest-part-installation-of-consecutive-installations-in-the-same