# How to get the oldest part installation of consecutive installations in the same boat where column X is False?

Tags: python, pandas

I got a nice algorithm that returns the oldest part installation of consecutive installations in the same boat: [How to get oldest part installation of consecutive installations the same boat in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726268/how-to-get-oldest-part-installation-of-consecutive-installations-the-same-boat-i)

I would like to only apply this algorithm on rows that have `col['x'] == False`. How can I do this? See expected output below.

Algorithm: `print (df[['boat','part']].ne(df[['boat','part']].shift()).any(axis=1))`

**Input**

```
| boat | part | date           | x     |
|------|------|----------------|-------|
| A    | B    | 12/19/13 08:19 | TRUE  |<-- ignore and keep this
| A    | C    | 3/24/14 10:26  | TRUE  |<-- ignore and keep this
| A    | D    | 7/21/14 09:46  | TRUE  |<-- ignore and keep this
| A    | D    | 3/5/18 22:35   | FALSE |<--evaluate this with algorithm
| A    | D    | 7/27/19 00:43  | FALSE |<--evaluate this with algorithm
| A    | D    | 8/9/19 00:53   | FALSE |<--evaluate this with algorithm
| A    | D    | 9/6/19 23:10   | FALSE |<--evaluate this with algorithm
```

**Expected output**

```
| boat | part | date           | x     |
|------|------|----------------|-------|
| A    | B    | 12/19/13 08:19 | TRUE  |<-- keep because x == True
| A    | C    | 3/24/14 10:26  | TRUE  |<-- keep because x == True
| A    | D    | 7/21/14 09:46  | TRUE  |<-- keep because x == True
| A    | D    | 3/5/18 22:35   | FALSE |<-- Keep because first install of consecutive installs
```

**Input 2**

```
| boat | part | date             | x     |
|------|------|------------------|-------|
| A    | E    | 12/20/13   03:27 | TRUE  |<-- ignore and keep this
| B    | E    | 7/21/14   09:46  | FALSE |<--evaluate this with algorithm
| C    | E    | 1/8/16   17:08   | TRUE  |<-- ignore and keep this
| C    | E    | 3/23/16   17:15  | TRUE  |<-- ignore and keep this
| B    | E    | 3/5/18   22:35   | FALSE |<--evaluate this with algorithm
| B    | E    | 7/27/19   00:43  | FALSE |<--evaluate this with algorithm
| B    | E    | 8/9/19   00:53   | FALSE |<--evaluate this with algorithm
| B    | E    | 9/6/19   23:10   | FALSE |<--evaluate this with algorithm
```

**Expected output 2**

```
| boat | part | date             | x     |
|------|------|------------------|-------|
| A    | E    | 12/20/13   03:27 | TRUE  |<-- keep because x == True
| B    | E    | 7/21/14   09:46  | FALSE |<-- Keep because first install of consecutive installs
| C    | E    | 1/8/16   17:08   | TRUE  |<-- keep because x == True
| C    | E    | 3/23/16   17:15  | TRUE  |<-- keep because x == True
| B    | E    | 3/5/18   22:35   | FALSE |<-- Keep because first install of consecutive installs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is create new helper column filled by unique values if `True`s with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html) and processing all 3 columns:

```
df1 = df.assign(tmp = df.index.where(df['x'], -1))[['boat','part','tmp']]
df = df[df1.ne(df1.shift()).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
  boat part            date      x
0    A    E  12/20/13 03:27   True
1    C    E    1/8/16 17:08   True
2    C    E   3/23/16 17:15   True
3    B    E    3/5/18 22:35  False
```

And for second:

```
df1 = df.assign(tmp = df.index.where(df['x'], -1))[['boat','part','tmp']]
df = df[df1.ne(df1.shift()).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
  boat part            date      x
0    A    E  12/20/13 03:27   True
1    B    E   7/21/14 09:46  False
2    C    E    1/8/16 17:08   True
3    C    E   3/23/16 17:15   True
4    B    E    3/5/18 22:35  False
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! I forgot to use the `reindex` part :(

Comment: There is a problem.

Comment: Could you please take a look at example 2 in my updated question? The current algorithm excludes the last line, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @dunkubok - Can you check `df[df['x'] | (df[['boat','part']].ne(df[['boat','part']].shift()).any(axis=1))]` ?

Comment: Input 2 works fine, but Input 1 doesn't return the last record.

Comment: @dunkubok - I think I know what need, but a bit complicated...

Comment: I've added some explanation to output

Comment: It's basically keeping first row of consecutive rows based on multiple columns.